# 3th time blown à Nano every

Tags: arduino-nano-every

Like subject all ready telling you, I blew up my 3th Nano every.

I mounted them on a perf board, soldered with 99% tin 1.0mm and a Flux, cleaned with flux remover, etc... When I then power them up through USB I have a short on pin 29 and 30 (Vin Gnd). And the board is ready to go directly in the poubelle (the garbage thing).

Second and third time, after soldering I scratched the space between both pins to make sure there is no connection. But...
Yip again. Is this a common issue? Am I overseeing something?

Did my measurements with multimeter. No shorts.

[image: pins]

[image: board]

[image: layout]

[image: pinout]

Comment: which perfboard did you use? ... what is the picture supposed to show? ... you have provided zero information about what you did

Comment: have you tested all relevant pins for connections? I mean actually testing them (for example with a multimeter)

Comment: those are not answers ... you are still providing zero information ... i did not ask you where you bought the perf board ... please provide clear pictures of the two sides of the perf board before any work was done ... also provide clear pictures that show what you did

Comment: Thx for your answers. I use a Ali express perfboard. The picture show the Vin and Gnd pin at the left. I want to show you the gap between the two solderpoints. The only thing I did was soldered the Nano in place, powered over USB en floep. Spark between Vin en Gnd. I tested all the pin with a multimeter. Didn't got saw any issues. Could it be the perfboard?

Comment: where exactly did you see a spark? ... the only time you will see a spark with a 5 V supply, is when two condutors are very close together or the voltage is much higher than you think

Comment: Can you post a sketch or schematic showing how all of this is connected. Your picture shows 4 pins but what are they, I cannot see the other side of the board? How did you determine you have a short>

Comment: posted the pictures in the question, dont mind the cap, he's there but not connected. I see smoke, and hear crakling sounds between pin Vin en Gnd. I power the nano over usb, the first time I used a bench powersupply. I thought that was the issue. Then I used legit usb powersupply from one of my Rpi's, same issues. The third time I used the usb port from my pc and scratched between Vin and Gnd to make sure there is enough gap between the two pins, as seen on first picture, first pin on the left is Vin, Gnd is second pin.

Comment: I took the time to hang the nano on my bench power to show you what is happening. What you're seeing here are pins 29 and 30 Vin and ground. https://drive.google.com/file/d/183kBK4hXRMbkuoGcrJJOLEInRQ5zVFIP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use pin headers and check for the shorts before you'll insert board...

Comment: if gnd shorted to vin, the nano should be okay.

Comment: What solder are you using? What flux are you using? What flux cleaner are you using?

Comment: i looked at the video ... wow ... definitely looks like contamination ... are you using paste solder? ... solder two bare pins that are not connected to anything and measure the resistance between them

Comment: measure resistance between two adjacent, unused holes ... the board itself may have a conductive layer

Comment: have you removed the Nano and tested it? ... it may be undamaged .... afrer the short circuit in the video burns itself out, the Nano may be functional, but being held in a reset state by a short between reset and gnd

Comment: @jsotola on your advice, I prept a perfboard like this, two bare pins using only solder, two with solder and flux, two with solder flux and cleaner. And apparently its the solder that causes the problem, and maybe the fact I didn't cleaned the board enough afterward? But ok, I don't think this should happen... I'm using Welco solder. Flux is from Weller and the cleaner I use is Cramolin. I desoldered the nano, I get a USB corrupted notif. When compiling I get these messages bit.ly/2WIK0d3 
 bit.ly/2WFt0nB

Comment: I don't know "welco". Is it an electronics solder or a plumber's solder? The same for the flux: is it electronic flux or plumber's flux?

Answer (score 2):

If i am not wrong you have soldered nano directly to the  perf board, which i don't recommend at all. You could try soldering a female strip pin on to the pref board and insert the nano board in the strip pin. This way you could easily remove/install the board easily as you wish.
[image]

Comment: Since whoever down-voted this didn't bother to say, I'll offer a guess as to the reason. They appear to still be developing the question.  And one of the comments suggests doing this exact thing, though, I think as a diagnostic measure rather than answer.